requested array would exceed the maximum number of dimension of 1 issue in gym
let us suppose we have folloing code :
import gym

from stable_baselines3 import PPO

env = gym.make("CartPole-v1", render_mode="human")

model = PPO("MlpPolicy", env, verbose=1)
# model.learn(total_timesteps=10000,)

vec_env = model.get_env()
obs = vec_env.reset()
print(obs)
for i in range(1000):
    action, _states = model.predict(obs, deterministic=True)
    obs, reward, done, info = vec_env.step(action)
    vec_env.render()
    # VecEnv resets automatically
    # if done:
    #   obs = env.reset()

env.close()

i have installed  previous version of both libraries :
pip install stable-baselines3==1.00

and :
 pip install gym==0.26 

but when i  am running code, getting following error :
   ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array would exceed the maximum number of dimension of 1.

how can i fix this error please?

Depending on the gym version, there are a few things you have to keep in mind:
env.reset
The env.reset() function may return the state and an additional info parameter. Depending on the gym version, you either have to:
obs = vec_env.reset()

or
obs, info = vec_env.reset()

env.step
Similarly, env.step() may return, depending on the gym version, an additional parameter truncated, which states whether the episode has ended via a non-terminal state-like position. This could be unexpected errors or exceeding the number of timesteps. You can treat this the same way as the terminated statement. So, depending on the gym version, you would want to:
obs, reward, done, info = vec_env.step(action)

or
obs, reward, done, truncated, info = vec_env.step(action)
done = done or truncated

